# Whats the difference between prop('disabled','disabled') and prop('disabled',true)

Tags: jquery

Im using jQuery to disable an option in a select drop down list. I need to know the difference between using

```
prop('disabled','disabled')
```

and

```
prop('disabled',true)
```

Both pretty much work on all browsers (not sure if I've missed any tho), but on another post I was he say use disable, true. Can someone please elabarate? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [W3C forms specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled), the disabled attribute is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2),

so `prop('disabled',true)` is right.

`prop('disabled','disabled')` also works because the string `'disabled'` evaluates to true.

Comment: Also, any non empt string evaluates to true.

Comment: @TorstenWalter Yep, that's the reason.

Comment: To add on, `prop('disabled', 'false')` will _also_ be the same as `prop('disabled', 'disabled')` because `'false'` is a non-empty string and evaluates to `true` in JavaScript. Ergo, always use `true` or `false` where a boolean value is expected.